# jQuery Sortable Newly appended elements not recognized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, refresh, jquery-ui-sortable

How does jQuery UI sortable method [refresh](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh) works. I have Multiple `span` tag with `P` tags inside. The `P` tags are sortable from one `span` to another. However when i add a new span with p tags inside, the new P tags are not recognized. The refresh method is supposed to make newly added recognizable. but it doesn't seem to be working or doing anything.  `$('span').sortable('refresh')`.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/ySP96/2/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that `refresh` is looking for child elements of only the containers you have already initialised with `.sortable()`. You're adding both child elements **and** containers, so you need to initialise those new containers with `.sortable()`, instead of using `.sortable('refresh')`.

```
$('#span').click(function() {
    var x = '<span><p>NEW Span</p></span>';
    $(x).appendTo('#form').sortable({connectWith: 'span'});
});
```

See the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ySP96/3/.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the purpose of refresh. Thats what i want to know. Give me an example of how refresh can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually as below:

```
$("#MyList").sortable({
        update: function() {
            var postData = $(this).sortable("serialize");
            $.post("UpdateItemOrder.aspx", postData, function(theResponse) {
                $("#ResultsArea").html(theResponse);
            });
        },
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            // Handle new items only
            if ($(ui.item).hasClass("new-item")) {
                // Refresh the list
                var postData = $("#MyList").sortable("serialize");
                    $.post("UpdateItemOrder.aspx", postData, function(theResponse) {
                        $("#ResultsArea").html(theResponse);
                    });
            }
        });
});
```